# Set x-axis values for dataframe plotting in Python when data is time series

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, time-series

I have drawn my graph in Python using this code:

```
print(data_filtered['ranking_datetime'])
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y/%m/%d'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.AutoDateLocator())
plt.plot(data_filtered['ranking_datetime'], data_filtered['ranking'])
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Which prints this:

[image: datetime data]

And gives this graph:

[image: graph]

Why is graph dates not correct? I can clearly see there are good dates in that column when I print them before creating a plot. It might be because my data is not very consistent - some days has several entries, some dont at all.

Answer (score 0):

Year  1970 often means problem with parsing or formatting. I checked my time series type (it should be `datetime`) with:

```
print(data_filtered['ranking_datetime'].dtype)
```

It was just `object`. So I changed type with this line:

```
data_filtered['ranking_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data_filtered['ranking_datetime'])
```